# Symfony2 - how to get external (public) and internal (local) IPs?

Tags: php, symfony

I know that

`$this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getClientIp();`

returns User's internal IP, like: 192.168.1.100 but I would like to get external IP which is more like: 84.56.69.5

How sites like [www.get-ip.me](http://www.get-ip.me) knows my IP and how I can get it in symfony3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClientIp` of the `Request` class should already retrieve the "external IP".

`192.168.1.100` is more like the IP of the proxy. You can see all of them with `getClientIps`:

```
var_dump($this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getClientIps());
```

If `192.168.1.100` is the IP of your reverse proxy, edit your configuration like this:

```
framework:
    trusted_proxies:  [192.168.1.100]
```

and retrieve the IP of your user with `getClientIp`.

Comment: OK, getClientIps retunrs array with one element - my "external IP", is it possible to get internal IP? like 192.168.0.20 ?

Comment: it's really isn't.. `net.ipcalf.com ` just use webrtc to access the local ip from javascript. That's mean that you need to get that client-side, and it can be easily faked anyhow.