# How to check if there is more than one user after IP?

Tags: php, symfony

I have entity Post which contains [userIp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510761/symfony2-how-to-get-external-public-and-internal-local-ips), this gives me information only about IP, I want to be able to differentiate between multiple users, even if they come from the same origin IP

Hope you understand what I need :D

Comment: I don't think it's clear enough what you're after. You are correct that IP != person, you need something else to identify a spesific user.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to be able to differentiate between multiple users, even if they come from the same origin IP. You should then use client identification techniques like cookies or something like this (if you don't want / need to set up a login system). Be aware, that this might not always solve the problem appropriately, as users can deny cookies or delete them.

Comment: In case you are looking for [user agent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24387851/5816907)

Comment: Chay22, what if there are two pc with the same browser version?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use cookies, as I mentioned in my comment. Here is a simple example:

```
$userId = $request->cookies->get('userIdCookie');

//Set the cookie, if not present already
if (!$cookie) {
  $uniqueString = uniqid();
  $cookie = new Cookie('userIdCookie', $uniqueString);
  $response = new Response();
  $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
  //Save the $uniqueString where you need it
}
```

This way, each user (well, to be exact, each browser installation) should be identifiable by its own cookie / unique ID.

As I mentioned, problems may arise anyway if users don't accept or delete cookies.

Also, you should have in mind, that in some countries a user has to explicitly give his consent that your site may store cookies (as often seen in a popup when the user enters the site for the first time).

Comment: so... your answer isn't basically a "just start a session"?

Comment: It's the same direction, yes, but usually cookies last longer than sessions (though you can configure the expiration time of both). Also, cookies are stored an managed on the client side, sessions on the server side.